# ResultProxy behavior depends on stepping in debugger

Tags: sqlalchemy

I just killed hours trying to understand why my queries don't work. Turned out if I step in the debugger, the ResultProxy returned from execute() resets immediately after stepping over execute(). The following will print out a bunch of records if I just run it. I can put a breakpoint on the print() statement, it will stop printing immediately. Or I can step through and nothing will print at all.

My db is mysql, I tried mysqlconnector and pymysql, same behavior. Any idea why this is happening?

```
# this prints results, but stops printing as soon as I start stepping in debugger
q = session.query( Contract.id, Contract.longName ).filter(Contract.symbol=='ABE')
res = session.execute(q)
for el in res:
    print (el[0], " ", el[1])
```

Comment: Likely a race condition of some sort. Do you have threads or multiple processes?

Comment: No, not in the simple script I've reduced this test to

Comment: Can you post your entire script?